# Getting a value from another function

Tags: c++

I want to get a value from another function to use in my HangMan game. Currently it's using a string of several names in an array, but I want it to use my function below, which selects a random word from my dictionary.

I've tired

```
string word;
cout << "Press enter to begin search";
std::getline(std::cin, word);
Word *myWord = Dic.ListRandomWord();
```

This seems to print out the random word, but it doesn't use it for HangMan.

Comment: Can you show what type is `Word`?

Comment: And in first block of code you wrote `Dic.ListRandomWord(word)` but `ListRandomWord` does not have any parameters. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Use `std::cin>>word` instead of `std::getline(std::cin, word);`

Comment: @zoska that's a miss type, i was trying something. also added my word class, which gets the word from the dictionary.

Comment: @jameskerr So what do you need this `std::getline(std::cin, word)` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListRandomWord()` should return a `string`:

```
string Dictionary::ListRandomWord();
```

then in the `HangMan()` you need to replace this line:

```
word = names[n];
```

with

```
Dictionary Dic; 
word = Dic.ListRandomWord();
```

A string array, your dictionary:

```
string myWords[size] = {"aa", "bbb", ...};
```

must also be defined somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has cleared up so much for me.